# SDcard cannot hold new files after mount it with android

Tags: android, micro-sd-card

After mount my 32GB Sony SR-32UY micro SDcard (sold by amazon) in android for a few months, I unmount it from android. It still has 11GB free. When I mount it back to PC, it can read files without any problem. It seems receiving new files, but once I remount the SDcard all new files will gone. However, the file system check is still OK.

I then used the f3write/read:

```
>   Data OK: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors) Data LOST: 8.73 GB (18313600 sectors)
>                Corrupted: 8.73 GB (18313600 sectors)
>         Slightly changed: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
>              Overwritten: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors) WARNING: Not all data was read due to I/O error(s) Average reading speed: 9.62 MB/s
```

The SDcard seems fake?! I cannot believe this, because I thought I've been using its 26GB capacity in the past. Is there anyone can share some wisdom on this issue?

Comment: I would backup all files from the device, then format from the phone and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: it cannot be formated

Comment: @LPChip I have some impression that I had similar problem before, it has something to do with android which try to protect the SDcard content?

Comment: Doubtful. But if you can't format the card, then use one of the SDCard formatting tools on windows to format it with FAT32 layout. But if that doesn't work either, then it is most likely that your card has died partially.

Comment: @LPChip I've tried both on windows and linux, nothing works, maybe the card is broken.

Comment: I have a uSDcard that has the same behavior.  I've even tried to write and format it on a Linux SBC that has a uSD connector so that I didn't have to use any adapters.  According to the SD Association, this is a known failure mode.

Comment: Yeah, sorry but it seems your card has died, and needs replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which type of SD card you're using (MicroSD?), and if MicroSD even *has* this... but some SD cards have a hardware switch on the side to make them read-only. When you took out the card, you might have accidentally flipped the switch, thus blocking any future write access. The problem can be solved by just flipping the switch back to the read-enable position.

Comment: A write-protect switch being enabled doesn't explain the OP's statement, *"It seems [to be] receiving new files, but once I remount the SDcard all new files [are] gone."*

Comment: @ParaDice no, it is a microSD, and it does **not** complain **unwritable**. It does receive new files, it just cannot hold it.

Comment: Also, MicroSD does not have a write-protect switch. Only the normal SD cards have them.